# How do I bind to whole DataContext in Ammy?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, ammy

In XAML it is possible to bind whole DataContext with `{Binding}` syntax.

Is it possible with Ammy?

Comment: Why not simply try it out? I suppose we can expect some own affords from a 7k-user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bind` syntax without Path, just like in XAML

```
TextBlock {
  Text: bind
}
```